# getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream is throwing a NullPointerException

Tags: java, null, classpath, classloader

In Java How could getClass().getClassLoader() return null?

- The jar the 'class' is located in is
  NOT located under common/lib.
- The jar is NOT being boostrap-loaded.

The ClassLoader for all classes within the jar is null.

Comment: Is consulting the standard javadoc a lost art?

Comment: insults are really not necessary

Comment: Apparently neither is consulting the docs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using any [endorsed standards](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/standards/index.html)?  I believe this would cause the classes to be loaded by the bootstrap class loader even though you may not be explicitly using -Xbootclasspath.

Answer (score 4):

From the [documentation](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getClassLoader())...

```
public ClassLoader getClassLoader()
```

> Returns the class loader for the
> class. Some implementations may use
> null to represent the bootstrap class
> loader. This method will return null
> in such implementations if this class
> was loaded by the bootstrap class
> loader.
>
> ...
>
> If this object represents a primitive type or void, null is returned.

Comment: You would need to be running as a bootstrap class (e.g. using -Xbootclasspath/a:

Comment: Thanks, I knew I was probably missing something mundane and over complicating the problem.  Let's hope this leads to a solution to my REAL problem.

Comment: I'm trying to help another developer that's experiencing this issue.  I was hoping this would solve it, but unfortunately it doesn't.  They're not bootstrap-loading anything.  Any other suggestions would be helpful.

They're using Spring to load the class which is CALLING the code where the getClass().getClassLoader() returns null